# EntityManagerFactory cannot be injected in CDI producer

Tags: jpa, cdi, deltaspike

I am using Weld, RestEasy and DeltaSpike Data for my project. The project's dependency description is as follows.

```
<properties>
    <resteasy.version>3.0.10.Final</resteasy.version>
    <deltaspike.version>1.2.1</deltaspike.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-cache-core</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-bean-validation-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-servlet-module-api</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-servlet-module-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image: project structure]

We used to use Spring for projects like this so there really was no need for the persistence file but we are needing one here so we placed it in META-INF.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.manmyanmar.hotel.cdiproducers.EntityManagerProducer.create(EntityManagerProducer.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:89)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:79)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethodProducer.java:95)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:151)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:183)
at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:744)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.getBeanInstance(InstanceImpl.java:178)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:98)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.EntityManagerLookup.lookupFor(EntityManagerLookup.java:58)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.createContext(QueryHandler.java:104)
at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.handler.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:77)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findAll(Unknown Source)
at org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.manmyanmar.hotel.frontoffice.service.RoomTypeService.getAllRoomTypes(RoomTypeService.java:22)
at org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.manmyanmar.hotel.frontoffice.service.RoomTypeService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getAllRoomTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.manmyanmar.hotel.frontoffice.restservice.FrontOfficeRestService.hello(FrontOfficeRestService.java:23)
at org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.manmyanmar.hotel.frontoffice.restservice.FrontOfficeRestService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.hello(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In case, you need the code for the producer.

```
package org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.manmyanmar.hotel.cdiproducers;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 * Created by Sandah Aung on 27/2/15.
 */


public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager create() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: `beans.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What container are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any details about your `beans.xml`, so this is just a guess:

Your producer class lacks a [bean defining annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations), so it might be ignored by the CDI container.

Try adding `@Dependent` to your `EntityManagerProducer` class, or check which bean discovery mode your application is using.

Comment: Thanks for answering @hwellmann. I tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work.